# Volume of a Rhombohedron Proof

Tags: vectors, volume, solid-geometry

I am trying to derive the formula for the volume of a [Rhombohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombohedron). I method is to find the three generating vectors and to then using the triple product to find the volume. According to the Wikipedia page on the Rhombohedron, the three generating vectors of a Rhombohedron with side length 1 are the following:

$\biggl(1, 0, 0\biggr),$\

$\biggl(\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0\biggr),$

$\biggl(\cos\theta, {\cos\theta-\cos^2\theta\over \sin\theta}, {\sqrt{1-3\cos^2\theta+2\cos^3\theta} \over \sin\theta} \biggr).$

I was able to get the first two on my own, but I am unable to derive the third. Can anyone explain how to derive the third vector?

Comment: 1) Do you mean a rhombohedron with identical faces ? 2) Could you give precisely which Wikipedia page you are refering to (I was unable to find these formulas) ?

Comment: if you can confirm that the three vectors are length $1,$  the next requirment is that the pairwise dot products are the same, in your case $\cos \theta.$  I would prefer constructing with an evident rotational symmetry around $(1,1,1)$  Let one generating vector lie in the $(1,0,0)$ and  $(1,1,1)$ plane, which is $y=z.$  Let one generator have $z=x,$   the third $x=y$  Suppose we fix  reals $(a,b)$ with $a^2 + 2 b^2 = 1.$  the three generators in my construction are $(a,b,b); (b,a,b); (b,b,a) $  while the angle between them satisfies $\cos \theta = 2ab + b^2$ A cube is $b=0,a=1$

Comment: @JeanMarie  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombohedron

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks ! I just skipped these formulas, although they were placed in evidence. These formulas are indeed for a **isohedral rhombohedron** (all faces are the same).

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, the three vectors are length 1, according to the Wikipedia page. Just to clarify, is the origin of your coordinate system (1,1,1)? Also, if the side length of the rhombohedron is changed to $L$, how are $a$ and $b$ related to $L$?

Comment: My origin is also (0,0,0).  For edge length $L, $  take $a^2 + 2 b^2 = L^2$